# paramiko: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, paramiko

I have created python C++ buindings and created **libMyModule.so** 
which I am importing in python program.

```
**libMyModule.so** is depends on **libAnotherModule.so**
```

both are in same location

in my main python file I am doing below thing.

```
a=__import__("libMyModule")
```

Its working fine when I run it in linux box.

if I call the same python using paramiko its giving error while loading dependency.

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('hiost', username='username', password='password') 
command = 'python $HOME/run.py'

stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(command)


print stderr.readlines()
```

**import ("libMyModule")
ImportError: libAnotherModule cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

**So now my question is:**

how **import** resloves its dependencies ?

As when I run file from linux working fine, any suggestion to make it work from another system using paramiko.
Any environemnt settings which I have to do ?